# How do I read Intellij coverage report?

Tags: intellij-idea, test-coverage

I am doing unit tests and I recently find out about the coverage test feature in IntelliJ. 
Things are pretty clear except when generating the coverage report I don't understand why in the more detailed view of the report it shows the `$$anonfun$x` (where `x` is a number) suffix.

I'll show you an example:

`Class    Method, %   Line, %
DataContent 100% (5/ 5) 94.7% (18/ 19)
DataContent$$anonfun$1  0% (0/ 1)   0% (0/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$10 100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$11 100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$12 100% (2/ 2) 100% (4/ 4)
DataContent$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$13 100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$14 100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$5    100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$6    100% (2/ 2) 100% (4/ 4)
DataContent$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$15    100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$9  100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$extractUsersIDsVal$1   100% (1/ 1) 100% (1/ 1)
DataContent$$anonfun$extractUsersNameVal$1  0% (0/ 1)   0% (0/ 1)
total   89.5% (17/ 19)  91.9% (34/ 37)`

Could anyone enlight me, please?

Comment: As the headers state... its the class name, the % coverage of methods and the % coverage of lines of code. Those numbers after `$$` are just part of the class name, usually anonymous inner classes or functions.

Comment: why the index? why the index 1 is at 0% and 10,11 is 100% ?
What is the fir `DataContent`? the costructor? is there anonimous functions in this constructor?

Comment: Sorry, that is dependent on your code. This looks like it might be scala or Java with a lot of lambda functions. I would need to see the source to explain further. Also depends on your tests.